# Is it possible to record the time it takes to serialize objects being returned from a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, performance, serialization, deserialization

We are looking at some performance issues with a web service we are calling.
I have managed to place time recording code throughout the actual webservice methods itself, but now it's looking as if the actual time it takes to serialize the result set could be an issue?

So am looking to record how long serializing this data is taking, but am struggling to get any results..

Here is an example web service method we have:

```
[AuthExtension]
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("AuthHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
public ResultSet CheckAvailability(FareSelections fareSelections)
{
    ResultSet results = null;
    results = Logic.CheckAvailability(fareSelections, AuthHeader.Token, timeLogger);
    return results;
}
```

I have tried, placing methods in the class being returned that are decorated with [OnSerializing()] and [OnSerialized()] attributes, but this doesn't work. I have also tried to capture timings in the method by making use of a try..finally block, but don't think this is recording the actual serialization time either?

It has been suggested that I may have to implement my own serializer (which would simply record timings and then call the default serializer anyway), but was just wondering if this was the only option I have?

Any thoughts very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Custom SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx).  In the ProcessMessage() method, you can see 4 events, Before and After serialization and Before and After deserialization.  Start a stopwatch in the Befores, end it on the Afters, then store the time away somewhere.

Comment: This might be the way to go.. I will place my TimeLogger class in there and will call it when the message.Stage is BeforeSerialize and again when the message.Stage is AfterSerialize - thank you very much for this suggestion

Comment: Cheers this has allowed us to identify that serializing the results is taking > 30 seconds for large searches.. now off to find a more efficient way of serializing that info and getting it to the front end.  Many thanks for the Answer!

Answer (score 0):

warp the call around a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) object

from memory:

```
  Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.Startnew();
  //stuff
  sw.Stop();
  print sw.ElapsedMilliseconds();
```

Comment: i don’t have VS or my project on hand so the syntax might be wrong but it's easy to fix

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you use the service trace viewer to check to see how long each request is taking?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [Ants profiler](http://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/&sa=U&ei=LnH_TP29FYbqrQfkvpGcCA&ved=0CA8QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHTg8jOFknmFNBfB-VQ2DwACkV0gg) (an eval version would do) to profile those methods in question.. it will give you a very good insight.